# Use Radio button on webform to open another field where data can be entered

Tags: html

I have webform with several standard fields, however 1 field I want to be either shrunk or greyed out or hidden until the field above it...a Radio button selection box with Yes or No options, is selected Yes...or even a check box would work...does not matter

```
<tr>
 <td style="width: 143px"><b>Add Notes:
 </b></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="cmtad" value=Yes>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="cmtad" value=No>No
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td style="width: 143px" class="style10"><b>Notes:
 </b></td>
<td >
<textarea input name=info rows="5" cols="32"  style="color: black;background-color:#FFFF66"></textarea></td>
</tr>
```

I want the Notes text area to appear only if Yes is clicked in the Radio button above it the Add Notes.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with javascript or jquery.

Below is an example with jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[name="cmtad"][value="Yes"]').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().next().show();
   }
   $('input[name="cmtad"][value="No"]').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().next().hide();
   }
});
```

The above code should hide the `tr` immediately following the `tr` in which the radio buttons are contained.  The `parent()` calls allow jquery to bubble up the DOM to select the next `tr`.  This is a sample code, edit as required.

PS,
Would a checkbox not be a better option for this?

Comment: yes it would be a better option, thank you for your help it did work, appreciated